# Asynchronous handling in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect

I'm using a custom hook to create a behaviour of auto signOut after 3 seconds. I'm calling this hook from my main component and deciding the state of login using **isLogin**. After setting the credentials, **setLogin** function is invoked and due to useEffect setTimeout gets loaded into memory. The problem is, after 3 seconds I'm getting this error,

**Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application**

*If you think that this is not the correct way of handling such a type of scenario then please guide me.*

```
const [isLogin, setLogin] = useState(someValue);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (tokenExist && notExpireYet) {
      setTimeout(() => remValue(), 3000);
    }
  }, [isLogin]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `setTimeout` call is called even after the component was unloaded. In order to clean up the effect properly between dependency changes, you should return a function that cleans up.

In your case, it would be something like this:

```js
const [isLogin, setLogin] = useState(someValue);

useEffect(() => {
  if (tokenExist && notExpireYet) {
    const id = setTimeout(() => remValue(), 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }
  
}, [isLogin]);
```

This will make sure your effect doesn't run when the component is no longer there.